# Hyperbolic Functions Inverse

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

Why don't we take negative values of the argument in $\cosh^{-1}=x\pm \sqrt{x^2+1}$?

and write only

$$\cosh^{-1}x = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$

Comment: why don't you use $\LaTeX$? do you mean $$\cosh^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}$$?

Comment: yes @ Dr Sonnhard Graubner it is x+- Sqrt()

Comment: Sorry i miss ln in first definition

Comment: To find an inverse function, you have to use a branch of the function that is one to one and onto. With a $+$ sign it is choosing the positive $x$ branch. Think about $\arcsin x$. Its values are only in $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ with the same reason.

Comment: There should be a minus sign not a plus sign inside the square root. The expression you have written is $\sinh^{-1}x$